# OpenCV, area between two curves

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I work with `OpenCV` library in `Python`. 
The question is how to select in separate `roi` the area across two curves?
Curves are defined by two quadric polynoms.

[image]

I want to find count of black pixels at the area restricted between curve 1 and curve 2

Comment: you want the intersection of two curves? can you provide an example image?

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Do you know the curve equations? Do they have a specific shape? How many of them will be exist in the image?

Comment: I don't know the curve equations, they are fitting by any optimization method (genetic aglorithms for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create mask by drawing [ellipse](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse), but you should have the following data from your equation,

- center – Center of the ellipse (here I used centre of image).
- axes – Half of the size of the ellipse main axes (here I used image size/2 and image size/4 respectively for both curve).
- angle – Ellipse rotation angle in degrees, (here I used 0)
- startAngle – Starting angle of the elliptic arc in degrees. (here I used 0)
- endAngle – Ending angle of the elliptic arc in degrees.(here I used -180)

If you got the above data for both curve, you can simply draw [ellipse](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse) with thickness=CV_FILLED like,

1. First draw largest ellipse with color=255.
2. Now draw second ellipse with color = 0.

See an example,

```
   Mat src(480,640,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));
   ellipse(src,Point(src.cols/2,src.rows/2), Size (src.cols/2,src.rows/2), 0, 0,-180,Scalar(0,0,255), -1,8, 0);
   ellipse(src,Point(src.cols/2,src.rows/2), Size (src.cols/4,src.rows/4), 0, 0,-180,Scalar(0,0,0), -1,8, 0);
```

[image]

**Draw it on a single channel image, if you want to use it as mask.**

**Edit:-**

To find the area, draw above to single channel image with color=255.

Then use [countNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero)  to get white pixel count.

Comment: I'd like to use `parabola` curve, is it possible to make that by this way?

Comment: if you know where your parabola contours/lines are in the image you can use "drawContours" with filled contours

Comment: @shellenberg  If you have points corresponding to  parabola, draw contour using that points as Micka suggested.